# Why calling this function recursively does not throw a NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-8, method-invocation

My question comes from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767800/how-to-refer-a-lambda/27767834).

Consider this code:

```
public class Test {    
    static Function<Integer, Integer> fibLambda = null;
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        fibLambda = n -> n <= 2 ? 1 : fibLambda.apply(n - 1) + fibLambda.apply(n - 2); 
        System.out.println(fibLambda.apply(6));
    }
}
```

The output above is 8.

What I don't get is that how `fibLamdba` is initialized? It seems that I totally miss how the method invocation is done because I though that this code would produce a NPE.

Hope my question is clear

Comment: What does the first line of `main` say?  `fibLambda = `.  Why wouldn't it be set...?

Comment: I don't see why it SHOULD cause a NPE.

Comment: @cHao Yes, but it says `fibLamdba = .. fibLambda.someFunction(..);`

Comment: Ohh.  You've never seen a closure before, have you?  It's a bit like that.

Comment: @cHao Is this really a closure ? To me, a closure is a function that returns a function that depends on a parameter passed to the enclosing function.

Comment: @Dici: Yeah, it's not exactly a closure.  But the idea that makes it work is quite similar.  The value of `fibLambda` is the one that exists at call time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
static Function<Integer, Integer> fibLambda = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fibLambda = n -> n <= 2 ? 1 : Example.fibLambda.apply(n - 1) + Example.fibLambda.apply(n - 2);
    System.out.println(fibLambda.apply(6));
}
```

By the time the `apply` is called `fibLambda` is assigned a value. Basically, the lambda expression doesn't capture the value of `fibLambda`, it just registers that the variable needs to be evaluated at the appropriate moment to produce a value.

Remember that a lambda expression doesn't execute the code appearing in its body. It's just a declaration, similar to how you declare an anonymous class instance.

Comment: _"Basically, the lambda expression doesn't capture the value of fibLambda, it just registers that the variable needs to be evaluated at the appropriate moment to produce a value."_ Thanks, now I understand. It was disturbing me now it's clear :)

Comment: @user2336315 Just to be clear,t hat's because `fibLambda` is a class field. If it was a local variable, things would be different. It would be evaluated right away, and its value captured for use within the implementation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis following your remark, I tried to make it local and found no way to do the same thing. Is this possible ?

Comment: @Dici Not directly. That's what [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27767874/438154) is trying to explain.